# Incremental alphanumeric

Tags: php, numbers, increment

I have to generate a 6 alphanumeric string and it has to be incremental to work with an api. This has stopped working because I have seemingly ran out of characters.

I started with a00000 and ended up at z99999. Any thoughts on what the next increment would be from that? I have tried za0000 and a few others but am struggling to get it working.

I know this might be hard to answer because it'll depend on the api, but any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: why not start at 000000 and increment in base 36? then you would have over 2 billion numbers to work with.

Comment: Why dont you try aa0000.....

Comment: I agree with doorknob. Or if you can't start over go aa0000 as suggested by @Nouphal.M

Comment: Thanks for advice guys, but tried aa0000 and that doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, so aa1001 seemed to work for some reason, but the next increment which was aa1002 didn't. I presume the next increment must be something different.

Answer (score 0):

logically i would assume aa0000 then aa0001 etc in the same way counting would be done

za would be used after yz